# BASH Kill processes for user older than 1 hour

Tags: bash, process, kill

I'm trying to write a one-liner that would find all processes for a username older than 1 hour and kill them. I have the following:

```
for each in $(find /proc -maxdepth 1 -user hobbyisl -type d -mmin +60 -exec basename {} \;); do kill -9 $file; done
```

The following part is identifying the processes properly:

```
find /proc -maxdepth 1 -user hobbyisl -type d -mmin +60 -exec basename {} \;
```

When running the whole thing I get the following error:

```
kill: usage: kill [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigspec] pid | jobspec ... or kill -l [sigspec]
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 for how to more properly read data by-line.

Answer (score 4):

In your loop the `$each` (`each` is not part of the syntax - it's a variable name) variable holds the process id and not `$file`

Try that:

```
for each in $(find /proc -maxdepth 1 -user hobbyisl -type d -mmin +60 -exec basename {} \;); do kill -9 $each; done
```

However, I recommend using variables like `process_id` and not `each` as it could lead to errors like that :)

Comment: `ALL_CAPS` variables are "reserved" for use by the shell and should be avoided in script code.

Answer (score 2):

Your `for` statement uses the variable `each`. Your `kill` statement uses the variable `file`. Thus, error.

Comment: Ooh, I was under the impression that "each" is a function parameter, not my variable. Lesson learned - many thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one-liner using ps,awk,xargs. Replace user `root` with the right one and remove `echo` from the xargs in order to actually kill the process.

```
ps -u root -o pid,etime | awk '{split($2,t,":"); split(t[1],t,"-"); if (int(t[2])>1) print $1;}' | xargs -I _ echo kill _
```

To explain a bit:

- pid is process id
- etime is the elapsed time since the process was started

note: this will work processes older than a day (because of the split thing in awk).

update: a little long awk but:

```
ps -u root -o pid,etime | awk '{split($2,t,":"); n=0; for(i in t) n++; if(n > 2) { split(t[1],a,"-"); j=0; for(i in a) j++; x=a[1]; if(j>1) {x=a[2]} if(int(x)>0) print $1 }}' | xargs -I _ echo kill _
```

Answer (score 0):

The `killall` command supports this natively if you have that in whatever distro you are running:

`killall -u foo -o 2m bar`

- `-u foo` - specify a the user `foo`
- `-o 2m` - filter by processes older than 2 minutes
- `bar` additional filter (only processes containing 'foo' in the command)